# ClassNotFoundException returned on every applet I try to run

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use a Java applet (any Java Applet), but I always get a messages saying "Error. Click for details".

When I do so, the pop-up says:

```
Application Error

ClassNotFoundException

jreVerification.class
```

When I click the "Details" button, all I see is the following:

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Beth
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window

f:   finalize objects on finalization queue

g:   garbage collect

h:   display this help message

l:   dump classloader list

m:   print memory usage

o:   trigger logging

q:   hide console

r:   reload policy configuration

s:   dump system and deployment properties

t:   dump thread list

v:   dump thread stack

x:   clear classloader cache

0-5: set trace level to <n>

----------------------------------------------------
```

I am running Windows 7 Professional, and am up to date on patches.

The problem occurs in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, regardless of what Java Applet I am running.

The error I quoted above came from here: http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

but it still doesn't run.

I have attempted the following to rectify the issue:

- Uninstall and reinstall Java
- Uninstall Java, reboot, install Java
- Uninstall Java, delete all registry entries, reboot, install Java

In addition, I have run Malware and Virus scans, none of which have shown anything of relevance.

Comment: Have you changed your PATH or CLASSPATH environment variables at all?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 is my operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me like a dreaded non setting of `%JAVA_HOME%`, `PATH` or `CLASSPATH` environment variables. Other than that, you are probably missing something in your code. Please edit in the code you have written, it might help us spot things.

Variables:

PATH: At the end of this variable, make sure it ends with a semi-colon, then write:

`C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;`

Assuming you have installed java into a directory called java on the C:\ drive. Edit the line above with your path to the bin directory of your jdk.

JAVA_HOME: Create a new variable if it doesn't exist, calling it `JAVA_HOME`. The value should be the path to your jdk directory. Make sure to end the value with a semi-colon.

EDIT:

Compilation is something you must do to all of your java files to be able to run them. What compilation does is to turn your java code (e.g. `public class example{` etc.) into something called machine code that the computer can read. The error you are getting is because the web browser is searching for a `.class` file - because these files are the machine code versions of your programs. This is why the JDK is necessary. In the JDK there is a file called `javac.exe`. This file is the java compiler - the program that creates the `.class` files. At the moment, it sounds as if you are trying to run `.java` files as executables, which is not possible. To compile your programs:

1. Open the command prompt. (Go to file explorer, navigate to `C:Windows\system32\` and open the file called `cmd.exe`.
2. At the command line, type `cd PATH_TO_JAVA_FILE`, replacing PATH_TO_JAVA_FILE with the path to your java file.
3. Type `javac yourfile.java`, replacing yourfile.java with the name of your java file.
4. If successful, you will discover a new file in the same directory as your `.java` file - a file named the same as your `.java` file, but with a `.class` extension. This is the executable.

Read [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html) for a lesson on compiling and running a simple Java program.

Comment: Its not code that I have written(I have installed Java on my computer and this happens every time I try to run any applet),my OS its Windows 7. Its JRE(I think)

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams so check your system variables. I fyou have uninstalled multiple times there are probably multiple java installations on your computer. make sure there is only one

Comment: I've gone to where all the likely spots are that Java is installed, and removed whatever is left, how can I check system variables to make sure it is 100% removed?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams open your file explorer at the top level there should be a button saying something along the lines of "system properties". Click on that, go to something like "advanced system settings" then "environment variables".

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium I will try find it now

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams what is the value of your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables?

Comment: PATH - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\

I have uninstalled Java for the time being, should I reinstall it and give you the details for JAVA_HOME then?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams reinstall Java, then tell me the contents of your variables

Comment: Okay Imulsion,

PATH - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\

There is no JAVA_HOME Variable listed here?

I'm guessing this isn't normal?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams perfectly normal since you didn't set it when you installed java. I have edited the values of the variables into my answer to avoid extended comments

Comment: I don't see it in your comments(I could be looking in the wrong place), would you like to chat on skype so we don't flood this page rather? My skype name is Leagueboost2 if you could please add me!

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams i dont have skype. but the edit should be there now :)

Comment: I see the edit, I've changed path, where can I find the jdk directory for JAVA_HOME?(I think mine is for JRE if that helps)

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams whereever java was installed on your system. for instance mine is located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03`

Comment: in my Java folder there is only a jre7 file? There is no jdk1.7.0_03?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams suddenly all becomes clear. You have not downloaded the JDK, only the JRE. JRE stands for **J** ava **R** untime **E** nvironment, and is what you need to run Java programs. The JDK, on the other hand, allows you to develop Java programs. This includes compiling and running, so if you install the jdk you will also install the jre. If you download the JDK you will find that all your applets work. Also, make sure to make some simple applications to test your JDK when you get it.

Comment: Thats what I was saying in the beginning :)

Do I need the JDK just to run random java applets off of the internet?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams no, all java programs can be run with the JRE alone. The JDK is only necessary for developing applets and applications (and servlets). But something has occurred to me. Did you compile your applet file?

Comment: okay downloading the jdk version now to try that, lets hope it works!

I'm guessing uninstall the JRE Version before installing the JDK?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams but did you compile your `.java` file? This is very important.

Comment: I don't think so, I wouldn't even know how to compile it :O

Comment: jdk version is now installed, now instead of getting that error, it doesn't recognize that java is installed and asks me to install the plug-in, should I try reboot my computer before we continue?

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams have just edited question with explanation. hope that helps :)

Comment: I am not creating my own class files here, this is happening when I visit any website with built in java applets,I get this error automatically when I visit any website with a built in java applet, for example :

http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

Returns with jreVerification.class

Its as if my computer can't access the .class files from websites like its being blocked? I turned off my firewall etc, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams you will need to install the plugin like it says to run the applet. I didn't realize that you weren't developing your own.

Comment: but thats the thing, I just installed the jdk version it is installed, but still asks me to install? Should I install another version ontop of the jdk version?

Comment: okay, I clicked install plugin, now I just receive the same error as before, you can link me any website with a java applet installed, and I will get an error with it. Its always returns a classnotfoundexception with a .class file.

Comment: thats weird...i am not really sure why it did that. I think this question would do better on super user rather than stackoverflow.com, as no programming is involved.

Comment: Okay, I will try my luck there, thanks for all your help imulsion.

Comment: @DevonShowTimeWilliams thats fine, but pls upvote my answer/accept it because i need some rep out of all this typing. I have flagged the question, a moderator should migrate it without you having to do anything

Comment: I accepted it as my answer, I don't have the reputation required to upvote it, but thank you a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Do check and sure that you don't have more than one jre installed on your system path. Some applications install their own jre and then insert that jre into the path variable.

Check the PATH & CLASSPATH and look for entries with "jre" in them. Or just search your Program Files for java.exe (if memory serves).

Edit your path to only reference the jre that you yourself installed.

Comment: Heya, could you please assist me with this Gaurav? I'm not a technical person :(